# Radio buttons are rendering as 'checked=checked', not sure of source

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a page with 8 different radio button groups (groups of 'yes/no' buttons).  Originally i had coded the html to render with the 'No' button checked, but now I need to render with no buttons selected.

I removed the 'checked = checked' and refreshed but the NO buttons were still selected.  I have refreshed again, cleared the cache, and run on a different browser to no avail.  I am looking for assistance locating possible causes.

My MVC code:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsFelon, true, new { @class = "commentBox RadioIf" })
    <label for="PersonModel_Felon">Yes</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsFelon, false, new { @class = "commentBox" })
    <label for="PersonModel_Felon">No</label>
```

How it renders:

```
<input class="commentBox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ChildAbusePast field is required." id="ChildAbusePast" name="ChildAbusePast" type="radio" value="True" />
   <label for="HistoryModel_ChildAbusePast">Yes</Label>
<input checked="checked" class="commentBox" id="ChildAbusePast" name="ChildAbusePast" type="radio" value="False" />
   <label for="HistoryModel_ChildAbusePast">No</Label>
```

Only other thing touching this is some jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input.commentBox").click(function () {
            if ($(this).closest('div.editor-field2').children('input:checked').val() == "True") {
               $(this).closest('div.formQuestion').children('div.hidden').slideDown(800);
          } else {
               $(this).closest('div.formQuestion').children('div.hidden').slideUp("fast");
         }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you pre-populating your form with `Model` data? If you are, check that those values aren't set to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't initialise IsFelon, then by default, it will be set to "False" which is the nature of the boolean type of object.

On the other hand, if you want the radios to be unselected by default, then you shouldn't be using bool, you would want to use "bool?" which sets the default value to "null" and thus none of the radios will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `IsFelon` property of your model have a value?  If it's a standard boolean, it will.  Thus when you map that property to the radio button whose value is False, MVC recognizes that they match and sets the button to `checked`.

The easiest solution I can think of is to not map those radio buttons to a model property, but just retrieve those values and set your model property programmatically in the controller on postback. You could also look into making `IsFelon` a nullable property, but using nullable properties in MVC can involve some fiddling around.